# Incorporating group charasteristics in multi-output regression setting

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, many-categories, partial-least-squares

I'm working on a multi-output regression problem involving the prediction of over 80 numerical targets using an equivalent number of numerical features. I have achieved encouraging results with Partial Least Squares (PLS) regression but I'm not effectively using all the available information.

I have a dataframe that stores for both features and targets some group characteristics. Features/targets belong to hierarchical groups with four categorical levels (1-4). For example, Features/targets sharing a level 1 value belong to the same group at that level, while different level 2 values indicate different subgroups within the level 1 group. The levels are encoded as integers. Levels have various distincts values, level 1 having the least with 10 distinct values and level 4 having the most with 70 distinct values.

My attempts to incorporate the group characteristics into my approach haven't been fruitful so far. I have some missing values so I tried imputing them based on group affiliation but it didn't yield significant improvements compared to simple mean imputation.

Therefore I have two questions :

- Is PLS regression still a suitable strategy, given the additional information about group structures?
- What methods would you recommend to effectively integrate these group characteristics into the modeling approach?

Thank you for your help :)